# программа не содержит статического метода "main", подходящего для точки входа c#

Tags: c#, mysql

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Подключение открыто");
                // Вывод информации о подключении
                Console.WriteLine("Свойства подключения:");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tСтрока подключения: {connection.ConnectionString}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tБаза данных: {connection.Database}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tСервер: {connection.DataSource}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tВерсия сервера: {connection.ServerVersion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tСостояние: {connection.State}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tWorkstationld: {connection.WorkstationId}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Подключение закрыто...");
            Console.WriteLine("Программа завершила работу.");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Пишет ошибку в 1 строке: Программа не содержит статического метода "main", подходящего для точки входа c#

Пишу на .Net core(5.0) пытаюсь выучить базы данных

[Весь проект](https://github.com/Fugur/DataBase)

Comment: Откройте msdn почитайте как main выглядит, или воспользуйтесь мастером для создания проэкта.

Comment: не хватает модификатора public?

Comment: Требуется C# версии 7.1 как минимум. Проверьте настройки версии языка в проекте.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, метод Main может быть и приватным, среда выполнения вполне поймёт.

Comment: Версия c# 9.0, что означает что ошибка не в этом

Comment: Вы можете скинуть весь проект архивом? Мне кажется, только так можно будет вам помочь, ибо код в вопросе рабочий, он может не работать только если 1. У вас старый C#. 2. У вас, например есть два `Program`.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на github с проектом

Comment: @Fuga, Вы б тогда уж на гитхаб-то не архивом бы проект выкладывали. :)

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://i.imgur.com/EnQx81B.gif). Смотрите что и как у вас настроено, какая студия, попробуйте может перезапустить ее, очистите проект (удалите `bin` и `obj`), перезапустите вообще компьютер. У вас полностью рабочий код.

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что этот cs файл каким-то образом не включен в проект.